# How to increment each character of string input by 1 and output encrypted string?

Tags: python, character, increment, caesar-cipher

i just started with Python and no programming experience before. I can't figure out one Task and it drives me crazy. This is my last station for my problem, before i cancel it. Following problem:

**Write a code that reads a string from the input, adds 1 to the code point of every character and outputs the encrypted string.**

**Sample Input 1:
I love ord function!**

**Sample Output 1:
J!mpwf!pse!gvodujpo"**

I know it has something to do with for loops, but i have big understanding problems with this one, since i don't know how to use them here. My idea was something like this:

```
_chr = input('Enter character(A-Z): ')
if _chr == 'Z':
    print('A')
else:
    print(chr(ord(_chr) + 1))
```

Comment: for _chr in input_string:

Answer (score 0):

You can handle things like this :

```
def encodeString(string):
    encoded = ''
    for char in string:
        c = ord(char)

        if (c >= ord('A') and c <= ord('Z')):
            encoded += chr((c - ord('A') + 1) % 26 + ord('A'))

        elif (c >= ord('a') and c <= ord('z')):
            encoded += chr((c - ord('a') + 1) % 26 + ord('a'))

        # and so on for other regions of characters

        # or collect the unchanged character
        else: encoded += char

    return encoded

string = 'Happy New Year 2021' # or : string = input('Enter a sentence : ')

print(encodeString(string)) #==> 'Ibqqz Ofx Zfbs 2021'
```

Comment: Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 2, in <module>
    c = (ord(_chr))
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 20 found

Comment: That's fixed by taking the first character of the returned string. Also I replaced 65 by ord('A') and so on.

Comment: I added a loop to convert the whole string